# Problem with inheritance and "self" reference

Tags: python

This is my first post, so first of all I want to say a giant "Thank you!" to the community of stackoverflow for all the time an answer did the trick for me :)

I have a problem while dealing with python's inheritance.

I have a parent class which contains the following code:

```
def start(self):

  pid = os.fork()

  if (pid==0):
   self.__do_in_forked_process()
  elif(pid > 0):
   self.__do_in_parent_process()
  else:
   print ("Error while forking...")
   sys.exit(1)
```

The __do_in_forked_process() method contains a method `self.__manage_request()` which is defined in the parent class and overridden in the child class.

In the child class, when I use use the method `self.start()` the problem arise: the self.__manage_request() method executed is the one defined in the parent class instead of the method define in the child class (even if, I suppose, when I do self.start() the start method and all the things inside it should refer to the child object instead of to the parent object).

Thanks in advance!

turkishweb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use *TWO* leading underscores in your method and other attribute names: they're **specifically** intended to isolate parent classes from subclasses, which is most definitely what you do **not** want here!  Rename the method in question to `_manage_request` (single leading underscore) throughout, and live happily ever after.  And in the future use double leading underscores only when you're *absolutely certain* you never want any override (or acess from subclass methods) of that attribute (method being just a special case of attribute).

In C++ terminology, single leading underscore means `protected`: subclasses are allowed and welcome to access and override.  Double leading underscores mean `private`: meant to be hands-off **even for subclasses** (and with some compiler name mangling to help it be so).  Rarely have I seem double leading underscores used with clear purpose and understanding of this.

Comment: You're lucky. Your first question was answered by one of the most prominent python experts in the world.